# Pandas: Insert dataframe into other dataframe without preserving indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to insert a pandas dataframe into another pandas dataframe at certain indices.

Lets say we have this dataframe:

```
original_df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

I can then change values at certain indices as following:

```
original_df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
original_df.iloc[[0,2],[0,1]] = 2

   0  1  2
0  2  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  2  2  9
```

However, if i use the same technique to insert another dataframe, it doesn't work:

```
original_df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
df_to_insert = pd.DataFrame([[10,11],[12,13]])
original_df.iloc[[0,2],[0,1]] = df_to_insert

      0     1    2
0  10.0  11.0  3.0
1   4.0   5.0  6.0
2   NaN   NaN  9.0
```

I am looking for a way to get the following result:

```
   0  1  2
0  10 11  3
1  4  5  6
2  12 13  9
```

It seems to me that with the syntax i am using, the values from df_to_insert are taken from the corresponding index at their target locations. Is there a way for me to avoid this?

Comment: Have you looked at the `merge` function? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do insert make sure change the df to values , pandas is index sensitive , which means it will always try to match with the index and column during calculation

```
original_df.iloc[[0,2],[0,1]] = df_to_insert.values
original_df
Out[651]: 
    0   1  2
0  10  11  3
1   4   5  6
2  12  13  9
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. A quick and clear solution. Thank you!

Comment: @user3053216 yw~ :-) happy coding

Comment: You beat me again by seconds. I'll delete my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

It does work with an array rather than a df:

```
original_df.iloc[[0,2],[0,1]] = np.array([[10,11],[12,13]])
```

Comment: Thanks! I like Wens solutions more since it does not use any additional libraries, but this definitely works as well.